# Calc Between Date On sql OR Asp.net

Tags: date, between, calc

i can Calc Between 4 Date 
StratDate: 1394/01/01 EndDate: 1394/01/30

Case1: how Calc only 15 day first

Case2: Continue 15 To 31

i have use Sql server and vb.net

Start from 1394/01/01 to 1394/01/15 = 15
continue 1394/01/15 to 1394/01/30 = 15

### exampel

15         15

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net than you can do something as below

Dim startOfMonthDate= new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1)

Dim nextFifteenDaysDate = startOfMonthDate.AddDays(15) 'gets next 15 days date

pass above two variables to your query to get results

Get last date of month for next 15

Dim lastDateOfMonth = startOfMonthDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)

pass nextFifteenDaysDate and lastDateOfMonth variables to your query to get results.

Hopefully this will solve your issue if not please add your code snippet so I can understand your question properly

Comment: i have long one years 3 level Original date Range Original Date  between 1394/04/01 and 1394/06/31 by table data Start Date 1394/03/01 TO 1394/04/20 how break date from 1394/03/01 to 1384/03/31 Display Calc and 1394/04/01 to 1394/04/20 Display Calc